# Can't move <nav> into some direction

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**EDITED**
I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and need to move navbar right(**not float:right, but move right on some value**). I can move it down, but it doesn't move right.

Css of my nav:

```
.nav
{
top:1px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #c893c7;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:16px;
}
```

My html:

```
     <div class="topbar">
<div class="navbar ">
     <div class="container">

    <a href="#" id="logo"> <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="258" height="130" /></a>

    <ul class="nav">                    
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#about">Download</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">F.A.Q.</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Support</a></li>        
        </ul>      
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Where is problem ?

Comment: it's very hard to tell, please provide more details

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: ok, I will try, but I'm not sure if I can.

Comment: You need a good question to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this solution is good, but I just put my nav in additional div and added padding in it.

Answer (score 3):

Add float right in your nav class

```
.nav
{
top:1px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #c893c7;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:16px;
float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/WmGpU/

Comment: sorry, but I mean MOVE right, not float:right.  I can do this, but when I try somethin like .nav{right: 100px;} - it doesn't move.

Comment: add position relative and then check i have add this in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/WmGpU/1/

Comment: I think, I will try not to use Bootstrap(for header), because it is not working with it.